# Evaluating math expression on dictionary variables

Tags: python, math, logging, evaluation

I'm doing some work evaluating log data that has been saved as JSON objects to a file.
To facilitate my work I have created 2 small python scripts that filter out logged entries according to regular expressions and print out multiple fields from an event.

Now I'd like to be able to evaluate simple mathematical operations when printing fields. This way I could just say something like

```
    ./print.py type download/upload
```

and it would print the type and the upload to download ratio. My problem is that I can't use `eval()` because the values are actually inside a `dict`.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: You'll need a more specific equstion of you want a specific answer.  There are lots of potential ways to solve that problem.

Comment: do you have an example of the data you want to handle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` optionally takes a `globals` and `locals` dictionaries. You can therefore do this:

```
namespace = dict(foo=5, bar=6)
print eval('foo*bar', namespace)
```

Keep in mind that `eval` is "evil" because it's not safe if the executed string cannot be trusted. It should be fine for your helper script though.

For completness, there's also `ast.literal_eval()` which is safer but it evaluates literals only which means there's no way to give it a dict.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the `dict` to `eval()` as the `locals`. That will allow it to resolve `download` and `upload` as names if they are keys in the `dict`.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> eval('a+b', globals(), d)
3
```