# Evaluate math expression but given variables instead of numbers

Tags: java, string, expression, evaluate

There are lot of math expression evaluators out there, but they evaluate something like (1 + 2)/3, and so on. But I need to evaluate expression which contains variables (in java). For example, if the program has two variables `int a = 1; int b = 2;` and if I pass something like `(a + b)/a` to a method as a `String`, it should return the result as 3 which is actually (1+2)/1. Actually the formula/expression comes from a config file.

Edit: Just found a similar question [Evaluating math expression on dictionary variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515397/evaluating-math-expression-on-dictionary-variables) , but need the solution in java

Comment: I'm confused. Does that line of code somehow not give you 3?

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: Do you want a **symbolic solution**?

Comment: @Matt I don't know what it is called exactly. I just edited the question.

Comment: I'm mostly confused as to how `(1+2)/1` returns `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by `(a + b) / a` comes from a config file? Is it a string you're trying to parse?

Comment: @Akshay yes thats a string from config file but they contain expressions with variable and math operators

Comment: @user3366706 You need to store a mapping from strings to values in that case. As far as I know (and I could be wrong) there's no way to translate a string into a variable name in Java.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think he wants to pass a string like `(a + b)/a` to a function and then get the result (i.e. `3`) depending on the actual values of the variables.

Comment: @Matt yes, thats a string which contains varialbles and math operators

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to translate a `String` into a variable name in Java. What you might want to do instead, is have a mapping from `String`s to `int`s. Then you can parse the command and retrieve the values associated with those `String`s.

For example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", 2);
```

The difference is that now instead of storing the values in a variable, you associate them with a `String` which you can find in your input text.

For example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("a b c");
String str1 = scan.next();
int val1 = map.get(str1);
```

Now `val` has the value `1` stored in it, which you associated with the `String` "a" earlier.

The next step is writing a parser for the arithmetic. That's a whole different animal to deal with. If you're looking for something quick to implement, I recommend trying to use [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) if that's possible. In any case, I don't believe that there's a quick solution that will do all of this including the parsing automatically.

You might want to take a look at this link here: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form?rq=1). It's not quite what you're trying to do, but could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parsers which will let you evaluate a string expression, but you must map the variables in some manner. I [rolled my own](https://github.com/Ben-Mann/evald) for numeric expressions, which I'd use for your example as follows:

```
int a = 1;                            //Given some variables
int b = 2;

Evald ex = new Evald();               //and an expression
ex.parse("(a + b) / a");

ex.addVariable("a", a);               //map the variables
int bIndex = ex.addVariable("b", b);  //optionally saving an index mapping

double dResult = ex.evaluate();       //evaluate (sets dResult to 3.0)

a = 3;                                //update your variables 
b = 9;
ex.addVariable("a", a);               //map new values using the string
ex.setVariable(bIndex, b);            //or saved index

int iResult = (int)ex.evaluate();     //evaluate (sets iResult to 4)
```

I've used more versatile solutions (ranging from [Jep](http://www.cse.msu.edu/SENS/Software/jep-2.23/doc/website/doc/doc_usage.htm) which uses a similar syntax to handle strings, vectors, complex numbers etc, to scripting languages such as [Lua](http://luaj.org/)), and the choice usually comes down to the software requirements - versatility, licensing, library dependencies and execution speed.